# Java, перевод exception на русский язык

Tags: java, исключения, перевод

Есть ли какая-то возможность перевести стандартные exception на русский язык?
Т.е. уже реализованные средства, а не ручками править и самому переводить.

Comment: Что именно подразумевает вопрос? Перевести само исключение? Или его тело? Вообще, перевод на любой язык не считается нормой в программировании. Все стандартизировано английским.

Comment: Текст эксепшина всегда на английском. Весь код на английском вообще, даже комментарии. Реакция на ексепшин, отправка какого-то сообщения для пользователя может быть локализирвоана, но это дургая история

Answer (score 2):

Выводить сообщение пользователю которые содержатся в стандартных исключениях не очень идея.

Я бы порекомендовал создать специфичные для вашего приложения исключения, содержание осмысленные сообщения об ошибках. И отлавливать их в каком то одном месте. Далее получать из исключений код или сообщение об ошибке и локализовать их с помощью `ResourceBundle`

Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
 String messages = ResourceBundle
                                .getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale)
                                .getString("database_error");
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html)

Answer (score 1):

Формально для этого присутсвует метод [Throwable#getLocalizedMessage()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage()). Однако тема локализации слишком обширная и в ней много подводных камней. У каждого для реализации данного метода есть свои велосипеды. А google-переводчик внутрь jvm не засунуть)